# Applet Jpopupmenu displays away from specified coordinates

Tags: java, macos, firefox, applet

I have an applet within a browser which has a popup menu but when the menu is triggered it is shown away from the applet.

Here is the [demo code](http://download.fastmodelsports.com/applets/AppletPopupTest/AppletPopupTest.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test the Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var attributes= { code:'AppletPopupTest.AppletPopupTest', archive:'AppletPopupTest.jar', width:300, height:300 };
        deployJava.runApplet( attributes, null, '1.6' );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This issue only happens on Mac 10.8 using firefox 21.0.  Safari works fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your problem?

Comment: The popup menu is way off where the user clicks.  You only see this behavior if you are you using Mac OS 10.8 with Firefox. (you can run this by going to http://download.fastmodelsports.com/applets/AppletPopupTest/AppletPopupTest.html).

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the behaviour and also the contents of your AppletPopupTest.jar. I'm cautious of running code from other sources where I can't see the code for myself.

Comment: I need at least 10 rep to post images

Comment: The code is posted here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618380/jpopupmenu-in-an-applet-on-mac-wont-highlight-menu-items

Comment: Anyone having the same issue?